# Delete query taking too long to execute

Tags: mysql

I am writing a shell script that loads data in an XML file into 7 different tables in MySQL.  XML file is loaded into all 7 tables based on specific criteria.  All 7 tables have an attribute 'PIK'.

I later check all the tables and delete all the PIKs that are not common across 7 tables.  This step takes 10 minutes for each table.  But it gets stuck while deleting records from 'PROEntity' table for 2 hours.
And the interesting part is that 'PROEntity' table does not have any non-common PIKs.

Here's my query:

```
mysql -v -u $Username -p$Password $database << EOF >> $ERRFile 2>&1

DELETE FROM ENTITY 
   where PIK not in 
      (select distinct(p.PIK)
          from 
             PRO p, 
             PRODET pd, 
             PROTH pt, 
             PROREW pr, 
             PROBUCK ppb, 
             PROENTITY_TEMP pbe, 
             PROMOST ps
          where 
                 p.PIK = pd. PIK 
             and pd.PIK = pt.PIK 
             and pt.PIK = pr.PIK 
             and pr.PIK = ppb.PIK 
             and ppb.PIK = pbe.PIK 
             and pbe.PIK=ps.PIK);

EOF
```

PROENTITY_TEMP contains same data as PROENTITY.
I had to use PROENTITY_TEMP because I cannot use PROENTITY inside the nested query and delete from from PROENTITY itself.

I've followed the same approach to delete from all the other tables but delete query on this table takes over 2 hours (even when there is no data to delete).

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Can you share the execution plan for that query and the table structure?

Comment: @Vickster, You must join all tables, then speed will be better. If you did not join, MySql will scan all records again and again.

Comment: @Vickster, try this `DELETE FROM ENTITY 
   where PIK not in 
      (select p.PIK
          from 
             PRO p
  INNER JOIN              PRODET pd ON (p.PIK = pd. PIK )
  INNER JOIN              PROTH pt ON (pd.PIK = pt.PIK )
  INNER JOIN               PROREW pr ON (pt.PIK = pr.PIK )
  INNER JOIN              PROBUCK ppb ON ( pr.PIK = ppb.PIK )
  INNER JOIN              PROENTITY_TEMP pbe ON (ppb.PIK = pbe.PIK )
  INNER JOIN              PROMOST ps ON (pbe.PIK=ps.PIK)
GROUP BY p.PIK
);`

Comment: @Ngoc Nam, Thank you. i'll try that. But why does it take 2 hours just for PROENTITY table?

Comment: @Vickster, I do not know structure of PROENTITY, but BIGGEST problem is: PROENTITY has too much data, whatever they have same PIK key or not. Because  you did not do JOIN in FROM, so MySql will read all records in all table every time.

Answer (score 0):

Use explicit join syntax and not (old 1992) implicit join syntax based on where (this is not for performance but for readability).

And for performance try change your NOT IN clause in a left join where the join condition fails (is null):

```
delete from ENTITY 
LEFT JOIN (
  select distinct(p.PIK)
  from PRO p
  INNER JOIN PRODET pd ON p.PIK = pd. PIK 
  INNER JOIN PROTH pt ON pd.PIK = pt.PIK 
  INNER JOIN PROREW pr ON pt.PIK = pr.PIK 
  INNER JOIN PROBUCK ppb ON pr.PIK = ppb.PIK 
  INNER JOIN PROENTITY_TEMP pbe ON pb.PIK = pbe.PIK 
  INNER JOIN PROMOST ps ON be.PIK=ps.PIK 
) t on E.PIK = t.PIK 
WHERE t.PIK is null
```

And last be sure that all the column you need for JOIN are properly indexed.